# Is there a way to grab/trap all keyboard events using Python and GTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to write a program in python that behaves like a screensaver or screenlock.

I can prevent the interactive user from interacting with other running applications by calling gtk.gdk.keyboard_grab and gtk.gdk.pointer_grab.

However, the user can still press ctrl-alt-F1 to F7 to switch to the console.  The user can also press ctrl-alt-esc to run xkill or press ctrl-alt-backspace to restart X.

Is there a way, using only python and GTK (pygtk), to prevent users from doing this?

The application is primarily targeted to run on linux mate.

Comment: To handle all inputs would be very backend specific (X11) at a layer below Gtk, I'd probably see the source for *gnome-screensaver* to see how they handle it.

Comment: @TingPing I was afraid that may be the case.  I've looked at the sources of XScreenSaver (written in C).  It is using XLib, I don't have any idea if its possible to work with XLib (probably using XCB) in python and use GTK as the primary UI.